# new Date().toLocaleString('en-IN') gives different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

`new Date().toLocaleString('en-IN')` is showing different result with different date formats in different enviornments

AWS `LightSail` instance running `node 12.20.2` shows `'5/14/2021, 1:47:06 PM'` and

`Local system` running `node v14.17.0` shows `'14/5/2021, 7:21:40 pm'`

why is this ?

Comment: Full ICU support only came in Node 13.  If you want support for 12 you will need to install a package.   More info here -> https://nodejs.medium.com/node-js-12-to-lts-and-node-js-13-is-here-e28d6a4a2bd

Comment: @Keith can you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: You could use this package to install the locales for the version of node your require it for -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu

Comment: The result of *toLocaleString* is specified as being [implementation dependent](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring), you should expect differences.